# using a look up table to query a many to many relationship and return all that meet the criteria

Tags: linq

The tables look like this:

Table `Film` has a `filmID`.

Table `Film_actor_lookup` has a `FilmID` and a `ActorID`.

Film `Actor` has an `ActorID`.

The `Film_actor_lookup` table is used to solve the many to many relationship of films and actors

I know this code is not quite right, not sure where to go with it.

```
public IEnumerable<Film> getAllFilms(Actor ActorName)
    {
         return(FilmEntity.Films.Where(A => A.Actors.Equals(ActorName)));
    }
```

Is this code doing what I need it to and return all films that the Actor is in?

Answer (score 0):

```
return(Films.Where(f => f.Actors.Any(act=>act.Name == ActorName)));
```

You can look for a `Film` which has an actor matching the name. You should be able to query directly against `Films`.

You can also go by `Actor`

```
Actors.Where(act=>act.Name == ActorName).SelectMany(act=>act.Films).Distinct()
```