# LINQ to Entities using a lookup table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, lookup-tables

In this database, There is a films table, an actor table and a film_actorLookup table to manage the many to many relationship between actors and films.

```
public IEnumerable<Film> getAllFilms(Actor CurrentActor)
{
    return  FilmEntity.Actors.Where(a => a.ActorID == CurrentActor.ActorID)
                      .SelectMany(a => a.Films);                          
}
```

Error   1   'FilmWebApplication.Models.Actor' does not contain a definition for 'Films' and no extension method 'Films' accepting a first argument of type 'FilmWebApplication.Models.Actor' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\newWorkPC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FilmWebApplication\FilmWebApplication\Models\DataHandling.cs   30  46  FilmWebApplication

Comment: Your current solution has a lot of problems, to mention the most crucial ones: 1. is highly inefficient, because you make multiple DB calls instead of one call to get all the data. 2. You're overriding `FilmList` at each call within `foreach` loop, instead of appending results to existing set of items.

Answer (score 0):

```
var films = context.Actors.Where(a=>a.ActorID == ActorName.ActorID)
                          .SelectMany(a=>a.Films)
```

Given all the foreign keys are setup properly. If not you can do joins manually.

Also a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23915406/693272)

Comment: The foreign keys go from the films table to the lookup table then from the lookup table to the actor table.  What is confusing me is how to write the appropriate statement in linq.  How do I specify the correct joins?